# How to open GeoTIFF header

Tags: geotiff-tiff

I have some GeoTiff files. I want read their header and save it to .txt

I've tried several programs, but none of them work properly. If u know some GeoTiff reader let me know ;)

Comment: What was one program that you tried, how did you try to use it and in what way did it not work properly?

Comment: I have the felling by header he means stored metadata.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that @nickves is correct and you talking about the stored metadata, I would do this with gdal. Use `gdalinfo` and direct the output to a text file:

`$: gdalinfo mygeotiff.tif > mygeotiff_metadata.txt 2>&1`

The mygeotiff_metadata.txt file will be created (or overwritten if it already exists) in the directory from which you run the command. I'm using windows, but I'm pretty sure the syntax is the same on Linux.  Don't know about iOS.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I used libgeotiff and in particular listgeo to export geotiff metadata. See http://trac.osgeo.org/geotiff/.

There is both a win32 gui and command line exe available for download.